# (Libgdx) BitmapFont color and Opengl 2

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

I noticed that when I use opengl 2 the bitmapfont color doesn't work
It always display my font black.
**How to solve this ?**

code :

In create()

```
BitmapFont font;
font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/arial.fnt"),Gdx.files.internal("font/arial_0.png"),false);
font.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

In render()

```
font.draw(batch, "test", 10, 10);
```

The output is test in black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't the text color from the png file wich was already white, but the background color wich was Black. I turned it into transparent and it worked.
Btw thanks to Lestat to put me on a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make your font white from the png file. The font color gets drawed on top of the original color. White on black is still black.

Comment: it's already white, and it's  works using opengl 1 but not with opengl 2, and due to some library I must use opengl 2 in my program

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to stop using `setColor(Color.WHITE)` and instead use `setColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)`. I also found that `batch.setColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)` worked equally well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading this then you may have encountered an issue with similar symptoms that I just encountered and arrived at this page:

Problem:
Label text won't show up on a black background or just defaults to black and you can't change the colour.

Solution I found:
Ensure you export your fonts at 32-bit depth, white with alpha. Try again; et voila:

```
//create font
white = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/white.fnt"), false);
//create label with associated style
LabelStyle headingStyle = new LabelStyle(white, Color.WHITE);
heading = new Label(MainActivity.TITLE, headingStyle);
```